# Halogy dashboard is not displaying graph

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, halogy

I am using halogy cms built on Codeigniter.
i have installed it successfully. 
its working in the sub folder but i am having a problem because i see dashboard statistics are not displayed.
I configured it couple of months ago and the dashboard was being displayed but i can't remember how i did it.
Any help?
Here is what i have modified

```
config/site_config.php
$config['uploadsPath']      =   'static/uploads';
$config['staticPath']       =   '/halogy/static';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a little fix to this problem. Here is how you can do it.

In `halogy/config/site_config.php` add this line

```
$config['appFolder']            =   '/halogy';
```

where `halogy` is the name of folder me application resides.
Next add a function in `helpers/halogy_helper.php`

```
function addFolder($string){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $folder =   $CI->config->item('appFolder');
    return $folder  .   $string;
}
```

Next search the function `display_image` and add this line

```
$path   =   addFolder($path);
```

Before

```
$imageHTML = '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="'.$alt.'" ';
```

Next go to `views/includes/header.php` and add this code in head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function base_url(){
    return '<?php echo base_url();?>';
}
</script>
```

Next fo to `static/js/jquery.flot.init.js` and replace this

```
base_url()+'admin/stats/'+days
```

with this

```
'admin/stats/'+days
```

Finally go to line 206 and replace this line

```
$imagePath = $imageData['src'];
```

with this

```
$imagePath = addFolder($imageData['src']);
```

Now the image problem has been solved and also the dashboard will work properly.