# Halogy cms not showing images or urls not working

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, halogy

I am hoping someone can help me, I setup Halogy on a local XAMPP host which is working fine.

I then uploaded it to my web server and did all the changes to db config and sites in the database, it loads the text on the site fine but all images are missing. If I click on services for example I get an error `cannot display webpage`.

I have tried CodeIgniter `.htacess` and Joomla one and the Joomla one makes the pages and admin work, but the images arestill broken and stats graph doesn't work.

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3) is my web server setup

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

This is not server problem. Halogy usually needs to be installed in the base folder of server host. Also i encountered the same problem and resolved it using some changes in application/config/site_config.php.

For Dashboard setting take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663517/halogy-dashboard-is-not-displaying-graph) answer of mine.