# Halogy codeigniter cms not showing images and urls not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, halogy

today i have downloaded  halogy cms from their site .. i successfully installed into me localserver on the root folder  .. e.g localhost/halogy .. i set up database and made changes in the database.php file successfully but the problem is the images are not showing and the urls are not working .. dont know what should i do as i am new in code igniter ...i have seen this question also  [halogy cms not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627662/halogy-cms-not-showing-images-or-urls-not-working)..but it didnt help too ...

Comment: what is your CI base_url set to (in config.php)? do your urls work if you include index.php or not?

Comment: it is working now actually what i have done wrong is i rename the root folder but now what i am facing the problem is i am getting this error ...                                                 Slight problem...

This domain has not been configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little fix to this problem. Here is how you can do it.

In `halogy/config/site_config.php` add this line

```
$config['appFolder']            =   '/halogy';
```

where `halogy` is the name of folder me application resides.
Next add a function in `helpers/halogy_helper.php`

```
function addFolder($string){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $folder =   $CI->config->item('appFolder');
    return $folder  .   $string;
}
```

Next search the function `display_image` and add this line

```
$path   =   addFolder($path);
```

Before

```
$imageHTML = '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="'.$alt.'" ';
```

Next go to `views/includes/header.php` and add this code in head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function base_url(){
    return '<?php echo base_url();?>';
}
</script>
```

Next fo to `static/js/jquery.flot.init.js` and replace this

```
base_url()+'admin/stats/'+days
```

with this

```
'admin/stats/'+days
```

Finally go to line 206 and replace this line

```
$imagePath = $imageData['src'];
```

with this

```
$imagePath = addFolder($imageData['src']);
```

Now the image problem has been solved and also the dashboard will work properly.